# Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Tags: python

I downloaded new source on 11-11-2014. While creating new module i got same an error.
If customize existing module i did not get any error.

ERROR:
    Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition
Error details:
Model not found: objective.objective
Error context:
View `objective.objective.form`
[view_id: 1413, xml_id: n/a, model: objective.objective, parent_id: n/a]" while parsing file:///D:/Development/Python%20Workspace/8.0-11-14/openerp/addons/project/project_view.xml:943, near

My Source code:

```
    <record id="project_objective_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">project.objective.form</field>
            <field name="model">project.objective</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Project Objective">
                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="name"/>
                            <field name="category"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="project_objective_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">project.objective.tree</field>
            <field name="model">project.objective</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Project Objective">
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="category"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="project_objective_list" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Project Objective</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">project.objective</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="project_objective_tree_view"/>
        </record>

class project_objective(osv.osv):
    _name = "project.objective"
    _description = "Project Objective"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Name', required=True, translate=True),
        'category': fields.char('Category',required=True,),
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was face the same problem while creating a first DB on Odoo. After installing `passlib` packages than it's work fine for me. I hope this will solve your problem too.

```
sudo apt-get install python-passlib
```